# Training model with same different input but same target

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am learning MLP, LSTM, CNN, and GRU models. During this project, I ran into an issue that I believe was caused by my dataset. I have four features, and I need to use two of them as input and the other two as output. The output features have the same value 10x while the input features have different values. Because the value above yields the value below in the input column, the order always matters, shuffle must be false.

Look at my dataset.

```
            
A             B          C   D
2986.207117 0.1249702   9.5 0.1
2976.566384 0.23405844  9.5 0.1
2966.936526 0.343854234 9.5 0.1
2957.317649 0.454363674 9.5 0.1
2947.709861 0.56559291  9.5 0.1
2938.11327  0.67754815  9.5 0.1
2928.527987 0.790235664 9.5 0.1
2918.954122 0.903661778 9.5 0.1
2909.391787 1.01783288  9.5 0.1
2899.841098 1.132755418 9.5 0.1
2890.302169 1.248435902 9.5 0.1
2880.775117 1.364880902 9.5 0.1
2871.26006  1.48209705  9.5 0.1
2861.757117 1.600091041 9.5 0.1
2852.26641  1.718869634 9.5 0.1
2842.78806  1.838439648 9.5 0.1
2833.322191 1.958807967 9.5 0.1
2823.86893  2.079981541 9.5 0.1
2814.428402 2.201967382 9.5 0.1
2805.000736 2.324772568 9.5 0.1
```

This is just one part.

The values in columns C and D will change after but in the same fashion.

Can somebody propose a technique to implement this situation because I discovered via a google search that having the same target is not a good for machine learning? Unfortunately, this is the situation in my circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

One idea could be categorizing the output. Let's say your input data is

```
  A             B          C   D
2986.207117 0.1249702     9.5 0.1
2976.566384 0.23405844    9.5 0.1
2966.936526 0.343854234   9.5 0.1
2957.317649 0.454363674   9.5 0.1 # up to 100 rows

3986.207117 0.1249702     9.8 0.2
3976.566384 0.23405844    9.8 0.2
3966.936526 0.343854234   9.8 0.2
3957.317649 0.454363574   9.8 0.2 # up to 100 rows

4986.207117 0.1249702     9.9 0.3
4976.566384 0.23405844    9.9 0.3
4966.936526 0.343854234   9.9 0.3
4957.317649 0.454363574   9.9 0.3 # up to 100 rows
```

Convert the output to categories like,

```
  A             B          output
2986.207117 0.1249702      1
2976.566384 0.23405844     1
2966.936526 0.343854234    1
2957.317649 0.454363674    1 # up to 100 rows

3986.207117 0.1249702      2
3976.566384 0.23405844     2
3966.936526 0.343854234    2
3957.317649 0.454363574    2 # up to 100 rows

4986.207117 0.1249702      3
4976.566384 0.23405844     3
4966.936526 0.343854234    3
4957.317649 0.454363574    3 # up to 100 rows
```

Now, one-hot encode the output column, so that you will predict the class depending on the class probabilities, and from the predicted class, you will know what output the given input generates.